# How do I dynamically identify recurring patterns in a list, and then remove them?

Tags: python, string

I need to find recurring patterns in strings within a list, and then remove those patterns from the strings.

The point is to strip website names of the document title, such that `Amet urna tincidunt efficitur - The Guardian` becomes only `Amet urna tincidunt efficitur`.

Using regex to do this is simple. But the problem is that the specific pattern is not known beforehand, just that it keeps recurring.

Example data:

```py
data = ["Amet urna tincidunt efficitur - The Guardian",
        "Yltricies hendrerit eu a nisi - The Guardian",
        "Faucibus pharetra id quis arck - The Guardian",
        "Net tristique facilisis | New York Times",
        "Quis finibus lacinia | New York Times",
        "My blog: Net tristique facilisis",
        "My blog: Quis finibus lacinia"]
```

We can easily see that the substrings `- The Guardian`, `| New York Times` and `My blog:` keeps recurring. How do I identify these recurring patterns dynamically, and then remove them?

The expected output:

```py
data = ["Amet urna tincidunt efficitur",
        "Yltricies hendrerit eu a nisi",
        "Faucibus pharetra id quis arck",
        "Net tristique facilisis",
        "Quis finibus lacinia",
        "Net tristique facilisis",
        "Quis finibus lacinia"]
```

Comment: You need a better example... if the pattern is not always ' - <website name>' you should at least provide a few different pattern examples.

Do you at least know the possible website names? or the different separators? it sounds like a tough problem if you don't know what type of separators/website names you'll have. It would require digging through your data to better understand it.

Comment: Thanks, I've added some more examples. Digging through the data is of course an option, my question is whether there is a way to do it automatically.

Comment: An idea could be to generate N-grams from all of your titles and create a frequency chart. Assuming you have multiple entries per website, you should start to see those bubbling to the top. However, I think you'd have to manually create a regex from your findings. Alternatively, you could try to manually label a bunch of examples and try using ML to identify them, but that seems quite difficult to do.

Comment: Does the pattern always occur at the start/end? Only one match per string? Is there always a delimiter? Note: your current example is inconsistent with logic. The two strings "Quis finibus lacinia | New York Times" and "My blog: Quis finibus lacinia" could be simplified to "New York Times" and "My blog", matching on "Quis finibus lacinia".

Comment: @aiguofer  Yes, that might work. Although the complexity of deciding what n for the n-gram to use would perhaps make it rather memory hungry.

Comment: @Ghoti Yes, only at the start/end and only one match. Some sort of delimiter is often there. However, the two strings in this case is not a problem since the real sample consists of several million titles.

Comment: @peterdalle yeah, I think it would have to be an iterative process.... look at some sample, find most common 2-8 word-grams, identify page titles, remove those from your data set, repeat. Unfortunately, there's few hard and fast rules in cleaning up data. I'll write an answer with some example code to do this "easily" in an interactive console. The fact that they're always in the beginning/end should make it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, do you want something that filters the words that most occur in a correct set of documents?
You can simply use the CountVectorizer from [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) with the cutting parameter you want. This is done using the **max_df** parameter. By the documentation ([CountVectorizer Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)) description max_df determines the following:

**When building the vocabulary ignore terms that have a document frequency strictly higher than the given threshold (corpus-specific stop words)**.

With this, you can ignore words with certain frequency. So, then just do the reverse process to eliminate words that exceed the limit that you want.

Exemple:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

data = ["Amet urna tincidunt efficitur - The Guardian",
        "Yltricies hendrerit eu a nisi - The Guardian",
        "Faucibus pharetra id quis arck - The Guardian",
        "Net tristique facilisis | New York Times",
        "Quis finibus lacinia | New York Times"]

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.3, lowercase=False, strip_accents=None)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)

vocab = vectorizer.vocabulary_
cv_matrix = X.todense()
new_data = []

for idx_t, text in enumerate(data):
    tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    cv_matrix_ = cv_matrix[idx_t].tolist()[0]
    new_text = []

    for tok_ in tokens:
        if tok_ in vocab.keys():
            new_text.append(tok_)

    new_data.append(" ".join(new_text))
```

Result:

```
>>> new_data
['Amet urna tincidunt efficitur',
 'Yltricies hendrerit eu nisi',
 'Faucibus pharetra id quis arck',
 'Net tristique facilisis',
 'Quis finibus lacinia']
```

Comment: That's definitely a good approach. The only problem could be that common title phrases might be removed as well, specially if there is a large number of websites in relation to the number of titles (that is, the document frequency for each website is low). I guess it depends on what's more important, to make sure you don't "damage" the titles, or to make sure you remove as many website name patterns as possible. However, this method could be better at generating phrases to look into, so analyzing the cv_matrix could yield relevant patterns.

Comment: I concur, nice approach!

Answer (score 1):

You could iteratively look for commonly occurring patterns and create a list of the most common ones to remove them. It sounds like you have a large enough data set that it's unlikely to be 100% correct on this.

Since you mentioned patterns only occur at the beginning or end, you could do something like this:

```py
from collections import Counter

data = [
    "Amet urna tincidunt efficitur - The Guardian",
    "Yltricies hendrerit eu a nisi - The Guardian",
    "Faucibus pharetra id quis arck - The Guardian",
    "Net tristique facilisis | New York Times",
    "Quis finibus lacinia | New York Times",
    "My blog: Net tristique facilisis",
    "My blog: Quis finibus lacinia",
]


def find_common(data, num_phrases=50):
    phrases = Counter()
    for sentence in data:
        for n in range(2, 6):
            phrases[" ".join(sentence.split()[:n])] += 1
            phrases[" ".join(sentence.split()[-n:])] += 1

    return phrases.most_common(num_phrases)

find_common(data, 8)

Out[145]: 
[('The Guardian', 3),
 ('- The Guardian', 3),
 ('York Times', 2),
 ('Net tristique facilisis', 2),
 ('New York Times', 2),
 ('| New York Times', 2),
 ('Quis finibus lacinia', 2),
 ('My blog:', 2)]
```

From there, you could pick out that '- The Guardian', '| New York Times', and 'My blog:' are common web page name patterns. You could then remove those from your data and run it again, iterating over it until you feel like you got most of them.